# I have two table (FeeAssigned, FeeExemption), I want to subtract FeeExemption from FeeAssigned and display in Gridview by selecting studentID in c#

Tags: c#

My table is like this

FeeAssigned

```
 =========================================================================
 FEE HEAD    |APR |MAY |JUN |JUL |AUG |SEP |OCT |NOV |DEC |JAN |FEB |MAR |
 ========================================================================
 TUITION FEE |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |120 |
 TRAN FEE    |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |50  |
 =========================================================================
```

FeeExemption

```
 =========================================================================
 FEE HEAD    |APR |MAY |JUN |JUL |AUG |SEP |OCT |NOV |DEC |JAN |FEB |MAR |
 =========================================================================
 TUITION FEE |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |
 TRAN FEE    |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |10  |
 =========================================================================
```

After subtract I want like this in gridview

FEEPayable

```
 =========================================================================
 FEE HEAD    |APR |MAY |JUN |JUL |AUG |SEP |OCT |NOV |DEC |JAN |FEB |MAR |
 =========================================================================
 TUITION FEE |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |110 |
 TRAN FEE    |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |40  |
 =========================================================================
```

Comment: Are these tables in a database or `DataTable`s in C#? Where is `StudentID`?

Comment: Yes it is in SQLdatabase, and student id is present before FeeHead Column

Comment: Mr Rhumborl plz help.... I am awaiting for your response still.